# How to close a video after it ends in a batch script?

Tags: batch-file, video

How can a `.bat` file open a `.avi`, `.wmv,`.mp4 or `.mov` file and make it close when the video ends?

Is it possible? If not, is there an alternative way to do that?

Comment: `.bat` file can't display a `gif` on it's own but it can call a command line program to do it.  Here are two to consider: http://www.gdsw.at/graphics/irfantut/commopti.html and http://www.pictview.com/

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid  My coworker somehow misunderstand her own scripts, she wants me to ask about 'video' files, not 'gif' files. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timeout command should do the deed for you if you know the fixed values of the vidoes your running.
Ex.

```
start video.mp4
timeout 10 >nul
TASKKILL VLC.exe
```

Comment: I try to stay inside the walls of batch so if i need to give the script to another person then they dont have to download 3 diffrent programs to make it work :)